# Extract specific values from string

Tags: python, xml, regex, string, tags

I want to extract all words that have the following label `"w="`. Example, I will need, `" THAT HAVE RECEIVED NO"` from the string below.

```
w="THAT" v="22.23092" a="19.09109" i="3"/>
<r s="1480150" d="150" w="HAVE" v="20.66713" a="19.09183" i="3"/>
<r s="1480300" d="360" w="RECEIVED" v="18.70063" a="19.09165" i="2"/>
<r s="1480660" d="200" w="-SIL-" v="11.65527" a="19.09165" i="0"/>
<r s="1480860" d="210" w="NO" v="18.49828" a="19.09137" i="2"/>
<r s="1481070" d="4330" w="-S-" v="11.55029" a="19.09137" i="0"/>
<r s="1485400" d="4170" w="-S-" v="11.88606" a="19.09137" i="0"/>
```

I have been trying to use the following regex:

```
 matches = re.findall('(?<=[w][=])\w+',line)
```

However, it does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: You're not including the quotations in the regex. Your regex matches `w=` and then expects `\w`, which is an alphanumeric character. Instead it gets a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'w="(\w+)"',strs,re.DOTALL)
['THAT', 'HAVE', 'RECEIVED', 'NO']
```

Then use `str.join` to get a single string:

```
>>> " ".join(re.findall(r'w="(\w+)"',strs,re.DOTALL))
'THAT HAVE RECEIVED NO'
```

where `strs` is :

```
>>> print strs
w="THAT" v="22.23092" a="19.09109" i="3"/>
<r s="1480150" d="150" w="HAVE" v="20.66713" a="19.09183" i="3"/>
<r s="1480300" d="360" w="RECEIVED" v="18.70063" a="19.09165" i="2"/>
<r s="1480660" d="200" w="-SIL-" v="11.65527" a="19.09165" i="0"/>
<r s="1480860" d="210" w="NO" v="18.49828" a="19.09137" i="2"/>
<r s="1481070" d="4330" w="-S-" v="11.55029" a="19.09137" i="0"/>
<r s="1485400" d="4170" w="-S-" v="11.88606" a="19.09137" i="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something more like

```
re.findall('(w=")([^"]*)(")', line)
```

?